# Kibana 4 : label on Tile Maps

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, geopoints

I am new on Kibana 4 and I am trying to make some beautiful maps.
Once my geo_points are displayed on the map, there are some labels poping when I put my mouse over one of the circles.

Is there a way to add any information to this label (right now only the metric and the geohash appear) ?